# Selenium Data driven test- number read as decimal from excel

Tags: java, apache-poi, automated-tests

In the test some fields accepts numbers and it has been given in the excel. But when the data is read from the excel, it reads as decimals. for example number 22 is read as 22.0. I have used apache.poi for the test. How to avoid decimal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try{
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:Users\\dinu\\Desktop\\RegDetails.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("RegDetails");
        for(int count =1; count <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); count++){
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
            System.out.println("Running Test Case "+row.getCell(0).toString());
            runTest(row.getCell(1).toString(),row.getCell(2).toString(),row.getCell(3).toString(),
                    row.getCell(4).toString(),row.getCell(5).toString(),row.getCell(6).toString(),
                    row.getCell(7).toString(),row.getCell(8).toString());
        }input.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Test data not found.");
    }
```

Comment: `Number` is an abstract, while `Decimal` is derived from `Number`.
So, if you have a Decimal, you also have a Number.

Comment: But i want just the number, when decimal also is added then it results in an error in my application.

Comment: You can just assign the value to a Number object. Simply write something like `Number myNumber = object.getValue()`, where getValue() returns a Decimal. Due to the objects hierarchy, you can assign a Decimal object to a Number field.

Comment: I am getting the values from excel, so how to convert tht to a number without decimal points?

Comment: When you say "Number", do you mean the "Number" object, or a simple integer?
If integer, try the intValue() method of the Decimal.

Comment: I mean an integer. But how can we use intValue() when we are directly passing the value from excel using sendkeys method?

Comment: I have used 'driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys(intValue(Password));' but still its taking the decimal value.

Comment: No no, not like this. `row.getCell(1)` returns an Decimal, right? So check what methods you can call there. Do you have something like `row.getCell(1).intValue()` or `toInt()`. If not, stick with `row.getCell(1).toString()` and put it into an Integerobject: `new Integer(row.getCell(1).toString).intValue();` This is now a pretty packed statement, so it could be useful to extract the String value from the cell into a field and then convert that field to an int.

Comment: I was not able to do the intValue() or toInt(). However baseed on your suggestion i have created an integer object and has performed the task.

Comment: 'double A = Double.parseDouble(Password);
  int B = (int)A;
  String C = String.valueOf(B);
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(C);'

Answer (score 0):

Use this,it will work...

```
           for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i + 1);
            for (int k = 0; k < sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); k++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(k);
                String value;
                try {
                    value = cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    value = ((XSSFCell) cell).getRawValue();
                }
                data[i][k] = value;
            }
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation of how it will work?